# Unable to get new instance of X509Certificate2 - p12 certificate

Tags: c#, azure, x509certificate2

I am having trouble generating a proper instance of X509Certificate2 in Azure App Service when attempting to download a p12 certificate from Azure Blob Storage. This code works on localhost:

```
public async Task<Option<X509Certificate2, ApplicationException>> GetCertificate(string fileName, string keyCert)
{
    try
    {
        string connString = $"XXX";
        string containerName = $"certificates";

        var stream = await _storageService.DownloadBlob(connString, containerName, fileName);

        byte[] certData = stream.ToArray();

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certData, keyCert, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet);

        if (certificate is null)
            return Option.None<X509Certificate2, ApplicationException>(new ApplicationException("Error while capturing the certificate."));

        return Option.Some<X509Certificate2, ApplicationException>(certificate);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Option.None<X509Certificate2, ApplicationException>(new ApplicationException(ex.HResult.ToString() + " " + ex.StackTrace + " " + ex.TargetSite + " " + ex.Message));
    }
}
```

However, in Azure App Service, I'm encountering the following exception:

`Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeCertContextHandle FilterPFXStore(System.ReadOnlySpan`1[System.Byte], Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle, PfxCertStoreFlags) An internal error occurred.`

Answer (score 0):

> The error you are getting can occur when the certificate is not being loaded correctly.
> `Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeCertContextHandle FilterPFXStore(System.ReadOnlySpan1[System.Byte], Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle, PfxCertStoreFlags) An internal error occurred.`

- Check the format of the certificate by opening it in a text editor and checking that it is in the correct format.

Also, it might be due to the certificate is not being loaded from the correct location. Check the certificate that is being loaded from the correct location with the path of the certificate.

Use [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#use-azure-key-vault-to-store-and-retrieve-certificates) to store and retrieve certificates in your Azure App Service.

```cs
var cert_Client = new CertificateClient(new Uri("https://<your-key-vault-name>.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());

var certificate = await cert_Client.GetCertificateAsync("<your-certificate-name>");

var x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(certificate.Value.Cer);
```

Code in C# to download files from azure container.

```
string conStr = "Connection_String";
string cntr = "tstcntr";
List<string> Cert_list = new List<string>();
Cert_list.Add("mycert1144.pfx");
Cert_list.Add("mycert1144.cer");

string path = "C:\\Tools\\cert";

foreach (string blb in Cert_list)
{
    BlobServiceClient blbSvcClnt = new BlobServiceClient(conStr);
    BlobContainerClient cntrClnt = blbSvcClnt.GetBlobContainerClient(cntr);
    BlobClient blbClnt = cntrClnt.GetBlobClient(blb);
    BlobDownloadInfo download = await blbClnt.DownloadAsync();

    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(path))
    {
        await download.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Certificate downloaded successfully!");
```

Certificates from container.

[image]

Downloaded files.

[image]

For more information, refer to [X509Certificate2 Constructor.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2__ctor_System_Byte___System_String_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509KeyStorageFlags_)